# aws cli command from bash with jq to get S3 logs from logging bucket failing

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jq, aws-cli

The below script is intended to get the content of each entry in the S3 logging bucket and save it to a file

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Get the content of each entry in the S3 logging bucket and save it to a file 
#

LOGGING_BUCKET=dtgd-hd00

aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "$LOGGING_BUCKET" | jq '.Contents' >> entries.json &&
keys=$(jq '.[].Key' entries.json )

for key in $keys;do
  echo $key
  aws s3api get-object --bucket "$LOGGING_BUCKET" --key "$key" ouput_file_"$key"
done
```

Once executed I got:

> An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation:
> The specified key does not exist.
>
> "dtgd-hd00/logs2021-08-10-05-43-18-01393D975686FA45"

However, if I do it from  the CLI:

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket dtgd-hd00 \
    --key "dtgd-hd00/logs2021-08-10-05-43-18-01393D975686FA45" \
    output_file_"$key"
```

It works perfectly, getting the content and saving it to an output file as requested.

What could be wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$key` will be a quoted string, so you're basically double quoting the string, and S3 is failing to find `"key_name"` with the quotes.  You could remove the quotes before passing them along:

```
for key in $keys;do
  key="${key%\"}"
  key="${key#\"}"
  aws s3api get-object --bucket "$LOGGING_BUCKET" --key "$key" ouput_file_"$key"
done
```

Of course, it would be much more performant to use `aws s3 sync` and avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: Excellent response.!! Thanks